# What is equivalent of RegisterInstance<Interface>(new Class()) design time?

Tags: unity-container

I am trying to implement [design time Unity configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx) (e.g.: using app.config). I am struggling with the very example of how to use the  tag the ["configuring instances"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx#config_instances) section.

Their sample of run-time configuration is:

```
EmailService myEmailService = new EmailService();
myContainer.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(myEmailService);
```

but no equivalent design-time configuration given. If I do:

```
<container>
    <instance type="IMyService" value="EmailService" />
</container>
```

I will naturally get a "TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String" exception. Am I supposed to create some sort of type converter merely so that I could declare an instance? Is there an easier way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  
If you are wanting a singleton instance, you can do so via `<register type="IMyService" mapTo="EmailService"><lifetime type="singleton" /></register>`

Comment: @TylerOhlsen yes, that; and I might be over-analyzing, but there is RegisterType and RegisterInstance in Unity and they are different things, although one can be used instead of another to achieve similar effect. I was hoping to not have to mess around, and use the `<instance/>` tag to achieve what RegisterInstance does, especially when the very documentation on Unity lists the example I provided - in the very section describint `<instance/>` tag